# SharePoint Online file storage

Tags: sharepoint

We have a requirement to store documents in *SharePoint Online* as people copy files to a shared network directly.

Is there a way of automating this? I was thinking of a windows service which will poll the directories, find any changes like new subdirectories or new files, then upload them to a SharePoint Online document library.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to poll if you use a `FileSystemWatcher` inside your Windows service for real-time notifications.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

However, if your requirement is 100% accuracy, you will need to build in some sort of tracking/checksum mechanism to make sure that every document was 1) detected and 2) successfully moved to SharePoint.

You may want to have your service check the delta every time it starts up, and then subsequently only respond to `FileSystemWatcher` events.

EDIT: Per Tony's question below, here are some additional thoughts on getting files to SharePoint.

First, try a simple test.

1) Copy the URL of a document library within the BPOS SharePoint site. Make sure you're on a machine that has the Office Online sign in app on it.

2) Open Notepad. Type some random text.

3) Click on File -> Save As.

4) Paste the URL.

5) Attempt to save the file.

This works great on "regular" SharePoint (done it many times). If this works with BPOS, it opens up several options.

Comment: Hi Tim, do you know of any 3rd party product which does this? Also, are you sure SharePoint Online(part of BPOS) allows posting of documents via its API?

Comment: @Tony - not sure at all; the last release of BPOS was very limited as far as SharePoint goes. I assumed that you had already validated that. The next release of BPOS will have SharePoint 2010 and is (according to my discussions w/ Microsoft) going to be much more robust. I have another idea for getting files to BPOS; I will edit my answer with more info.

Comment: @Tony - Also, see: http://www.docudude.com/2010/08/syncing-sharepoint-online-bpos-with.html

Comment: The SharePoint 2010 workspaces look great! I think that would solve the problem, but I think new BPOS gets released early next year.

Answer (score 1):

File System Replication to a SharePoint Online or Office 365 document library is planned to be released with the "Cloud Connector for Office 365". With the current version database content is supported only, but bi-directional with V2.0